# Moodle Emoticon Filter not working in Feedback Module

Tags: module, moodle, feedback, emoticons

I'm trying to create a Feedback with the Feedback Module (Moodle 2.5), which displays some Emoticons in the answers of the questions. i activated the filter, but somehow it doesn't seem to be working. Also, the alignment, which i defined as aside, is on the next line.
i created a field multiple choice with this text:
`0/}-] völlig unzufrieden
1/:-(:-( weitgehend unzufrieden 
2/:-( eher unzufrieden
3/:-) eher zufrieden 
4/ :-):-) weitgehend zufrieden
5/:-D völlig zufrieden`

is there a possibility to get this working? i don't understand why it's working in moodle 2.3 but not 2.5
thanks

Comment: I am getting the same problem ... any progress on this?

Answer (score 0):

I resolved this by updating the filters and the emoticons started rendering perfectly.

Go to

ADMINISTRATION > PLUGINS > FILTERS > MANAGE FILTERS

and enable the "Display emoticons as images"